# How I can choose right type of worker in Celery?

Tags: python, celery, python-multiprocessing, gevent

I read documentation of Celery. I understood that concurrency can be implemented by different types: https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/celery/concurrency

How I can choose the right one (ex. Gevent of multiprocessing or eventlet) and why?

And another question - can I determine workers in .py files? Or I can only start workers from command line?

I have two types of tasks:
1.working with SQL databases and export data to csv files. 
2.execute some sql on databases

Comment: How about you present your use-case so we can give better advise on which implementation to choose?

Comment: @KlausD.  I have two types of tasks: 1.working with SQL databases and export data to csv files. 2.execute some sql on databases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on what @dejanlekic said:

1. Choose multiprocessing / prefork as the default and only deviate from it if you have a particular reason.
2. In production or production-like environments you should start celery workers from the command line using `celery multi` and a process manager of your choice like `systemd` or `supervisord`.

Answer (score 0):

Like with anything else, start with the simplest solution (here - use the default concurrency model - the `prefork`) and if you find it does not fit, try something else. The KISS principle.